# ASP.NET (4.8) with AppPool Identity - How to impersonate current user during a single HTTP Client request instead of App Pool Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have an ASP.NET Framework 4.8 app that runs in IIS under the App Pool Identity, but I have several HTTP Client requests in the app to services on the same machine that need to execute as the **current user** instead of the App Pool Identity. What's the best way to do this?

I've tried the impersonation solutions I've found on StackOverflow, but those didn't work, and the HTTP requests still ran as the App Pool Identity.

Comment: Is this an intranet site? Do you actually need to execute as the current user or just as a user other than the app pool identity?

Comment: If your goal is to pass Windows credentials from the web browser to IIS and then to another service, keep in mind that's the typical two-hop setup and requires strict Kerberos delegation configuration by your domain administrators. No solution on Stack Overflow is going to guide you better than the administrators.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to set a user "abc" as impersonation authentication.

This is a Framework 4.8 Web Form application generated from visual studio by default.
I add "Response.Write(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);" in the default.aspx to show which user is being used now.
[image]

If you check this website you can find it is using the APP Pool identity.

[image]

Now in the IIS Authenticaion module: disable "Anoymous Authentication";enable "Windows Authentication"; enable "ASP.NET Impersonation" and set up your user.
[image]

After this set up, you can see it is user "abc" now

[image]